# Open corresponding .cpp/.hpp in a new tmux pane

Tags: vim, tmux

### Desired Outcome:

I would like to have a few vim shortcuts that will allow me to switch between the .cpp and it's corresponding .hpp file (of the same root name - e.g. foo.cpp correlates with foo.hpp). I want to be able to optionally open it in the current tmux pane, open it in a new tmux pane to the right, or open in a new tmux pane below.

### Example Attempt:

I have made the following attempt, it opens it correctly in the current pane or in a new pane to the right, but I can't get it to open in a new pane below the one that I am currently working in.

This is in my .vimrc:

```
"function to be able to swap between hpp and cpp files
function! SwitchSourceHeader(dir)
  if (expand ("%:e") == "cpp")
    if(a:dir == "here")
      find %:t:r.hpp
    elseif (a:dir == "horizontal")
      silent !tmux split-window -h
      silent !tmux send-keys -t right "vim %:t:r.hpp" 'C-m'
    else " (a:dir == vertical)
      silent !tmux split-window -v
      silent !tmux send-keys -t down "vim %:t:r.hpp" 'C-m' "I've tried this
      silent !tmux send-keys -t :.-1 "vim %:t:r.hpp" 'C-m' "this is another way I've attempted it
    endif
  elseif (expand ("%:e") == "hpp") 
    if(a:dir == "here")
      find %:t:r.cpp
    elseif (a:dir == "horizontal")
      silent !tmux split-window -h
      silent !tmux send-keys -t right "vim %:t:r.cpp" 'C-m'
    else " (a:dir == vertical)
      silent !tmux split-window -v
      silent !tmux send-keys -t down "vim %:t:r.cpp" 'C-m'
    endif
  else
    echo "Not an hpp or cpp file" 
  endif
endfunction

"alias to call hpp/cpp swap using function
let mapleader=";"
nnoremap <leader>sh :call SwitchSourceHeader("here")<CR>
nnoremap <leader>sr :call SwitchSourceHeader("horizontal")<CR>
nnoremap <leader>sd :call SwitchSourceHeader("vertical")<CR>
```

This additionally seems a bit wordy to me, maybe there is a better way of going about it? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, you are aware that you can open several files in several windows and tabs in Vim itself, right?

Comment: also vim has a session system too, so if you are using tmux to save your vim split configuration, it can be done with vim too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am aware that you can open several files and have several tabs and windows and split windows using vim. I prefer to use tmux for my panes (I don't think my reasoning for using tmux over vim panes is relevant to answering the question).